# Best way to keep in sync data in two different applications

Tags: rest, architecture

I have 2 closed-source application that must share the same data at some point. Both uses REST APIs.

An actual example are helpdesk tickets, they can be created on both applications and i need to update the data on one application when the user adds a new ticket/closes a ticket on the other application and vice versa.

Since is closed-source I can't really modify che code.

I was thinking I can create a third application that every 5 minutes or so, list both applications' tickets for differences on the precedent call, and if the data is different from the precedent call it updates the other application too.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

With closed-source applications it's nearly impossible to get something out of them, unless they have some plugin-based setup that you can hook into.

The most efficient way in terms of costs would be to have the first application publish a message on a queue, or call a web-hook that you set, whenever the event is triggered. But as I mentioned, the application needs to support that.

So yeah, your solution is pretty much everything you can do for now, but keep in mind the challenges that you may encounter over time:

- What if the results of both APIs are too large to be compared directly? Maybe you need to think about paging the results.
- What if your app crashes and you loose the previous state? You need to somehow back it up in an external source
- How often you should poll the API to make sure you're getting the updates you need, while keeping a good performance for the existing traffic?